# Does SLURM support running multiple jobs on one node at the same time?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, slurm

Our computer cluster runs slurm version `15.08.13` and mpich version is `3.2.1`. My question is, could Slurm support multiple jobs running on one node at the same time? Our computer cluster has 16 cores cpu per node. We want to run two jobs at the same time on one node, each job uses 8 cores.

We have found that if a job uses all of the cpu cores for one node, the state of node becomes "allocated". If a job uses only part of the cpu cores for one node, the state of node becomes "mixed", but subsequent jobs can only be queued and the state of job is "pending".

Our order for submitting an job is as follows:

```
 srun -N1 -n8 testProgram
```

So, does Slurm support running multiple jobs on one node at the same time? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, provided it was configured with `SelectType=select/cons_res`, which does not seem to be the case on your system. You can check with `scontrol show config | grep Select`. Note that on recent versions of Slurm `cons_res` was replaced with `cons_tres` See more information [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cons_tres.html).

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set SelectType=select/cons_res or SelectType=select/cons_tes
and SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU_Memory
The difference between cons_res and cons_tes is that cons_tres adds GPUs support.